# Simple UDP reader

Tags: java, udp

I'm trying to read all traffic from UDP port 6610, and I can see the packets in Wireshark. I made a simple reader for this:

```
public class ReceiveUDP extends Thread {

private int port = 6610;
private byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
private DatagramSocket socket;
private DatagramPacket packet;

public ReceiveUDP() throws SocketException {
    socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    System.out.println("Succesfull socket / packet creation");
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        socket.receive(packet);
        System.out.println("Succeded!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to receive packet"+e.getCause().getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
    new ReceiveUDP().start();
}
```

The printout is:

```
Succesfull socket / packet creation
```

I.e. the script locks up at `socket.receive(packet)`.
Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you *send* the packets? In other words: *What* do you expect it to receive?

Comment: Are you expecting to receive unicast or broadcast UDP packets?

Comment: @Joachim - I'm new to UDP - Do I have to *send* something in order to receive something? I expect to receive everything sent on this port...

Comment: @Theodor: no, *you* don't need to send something to receive something. But **someone** has to send someone for you to receive something. Is there some **specific** traffic that you expect to receive? Some third-part program that sends data to that traffic? Because if nothing sends to that UDP port, then the behaviour of your program is easily explained: It does exactly what it's designed to do.

Comment: @Steve - How can I tell?

Comment: @Joachim - Yes, there is a third party program sending udp traffic on port 6610, and I can see the packets being sent with a frequency of 1/s or so with *destination port* 6610 in wireshark.

Comment: @Theodor: your problem seems to be that you don't know what you want to receive. **Why** did you choose 6610? **Why** did you choose UDP? **What** would you expect a packet received by your program to contain?

Comment: @Theodor: are they sent *to* your IP or *from* your IP?

Comment: @JoachimSauer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2853/discussion-between-theodor-and-joachim-sauer)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't quite lock on `receive()`, it *blocks* on `receive()`. Specifically, it will wait on the receive line until something turns up. For the purpose of debugging and testing, you might use something like:

```
socket.setSoTimeout(5000); // Block for max 5 seconds

while (true) {
   try {
      s.receive(packet);
      System.out.println("Succeded!");
      break;
   } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
      // Timeout reached, log this and try again.
      // Possibly keep track of the total number of tries and give up 
      // (break) if it exceeds a threshold.
      System.out.println("Timeout reached, will try again");
   } catch (IOException iox) {
      System.out.println("I/O Error: " + iox.getMessage());
      break;
   }
}
```

It's generally not a bad idea to use a timeout on your sockets, this prevents your app from waiting indefinitely. Whether this makes sense for your depends on your use case of course.

Answer (score 0):

Like Joachim Sauer pointed out, the destination IP was not set to my IP. Changing this solved my problem.